# Simultaneous jquery highlight effect on two input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen the `queue: false` parameter being used on jquery animate, but I can't figure out how to do the same with jquery effect highlight.
I have the following :

```
          $("#iname"+i).effect('highlight',{color: 'red'},1000,{queue: false});
          $("#iname"+j).effect('highlight',{color: 'red'},1000,{queue: false});
```

and expect both elements to highlight in red for 1 second. Instead, only element 1 gives this effect. I tried several syntax options to implement `queue: false`, but none seem to work.

Is this at all possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. Found it.
Had to use dequeue().